# Convert url in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Web-App. Somewhere in my page I used following code to create a `Hyperlink`.

```
<a href="<%= Eval("NavigateUrl") %>"> <%= Eval("text") %> </a>
```

as you see this code must be work but there is a little problem. content of `NavigateUrl` is something like this url.

```
"~/account/login.aspx"
```

**How I must resolve that URL?**

***Update*** : I must say I cant Change value of `NavigateUrl` cuz that load from Xml-Datasource. I must change that in UI something like:

```
Eval( Resolveurl("NavigateUrl") )
```

Comment: what exactly is the error you're getting? try removing the ~ from the url, just use "/account/login.aspx"

Comment: page not found. cuz maybe current page is different place from where I want navigate to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [Control.ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx).

Typically you would use `Page.ResolveUrl` to resolve a path relative to the current page, and `this.ResolveUrl` to resolve a path relative to the current control (UserControl or Page).

In your case, the tilde is relative to the application root, so either will do.

In response to your comment, you want to use something like:

```
ResolveUrl( (string)Eval("NavigateUrl"))
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked.Code must be something like `<%# ResolveUrl((String)Eval("NavigateUrl")) %>`